# Can't Upload Sketches to Arduino Nano Every

Tags: arduino-nano, sketch, uploading, debugging

first-time builder here.  I just got my Arduino Nano Every in the mail from Mouser, and I'm trying to upload a modified version of the blink example to my new brand-new board.  However, every time I try to upload a sketch, the IDE just spins its wheels for around 5 minutes before giving up.  I've been trying to look through similar questions and haven't found anything that has solved my issue.  My OS is Windows 10.

Here's a snippet of the log (I've turned on verbose reporting for compilation and upload):

```
Arduino: 1.8.13 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino Nano Every, None (ATMEGA4809)"
…
Forcing reset using 1200bps open/close on port COM1
…
         Using Port                    : COM1
         Using Programmer              : jtag2updi
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200
avrdude: jtagmkII_getsync(): sign-on command: status -1
avrdude: jtagmkII_getsync(): sign-on command: status -1
avrdude: jtagmkII_getsync(): sign-on command: status -1
avrdude: jtagmkII_getsync(): sign-on command: status -1
avrdude: jtagmkII_getsync(): sign-on command: status -1
avrdude: jtagmkII_getsync(): sign-on command: status -1
avrdude: jtagmkII_getsync(): sign-on command: status -1
avrdude: jtagmkII_getsync(): sign-on command: status -1
avrdude: jtagmkII_getsync(): sign-on command: status -1
avrdude: jtagmkII_getsync(): sign-on command: status -1
avrdude: jtagmkII_getsync(): sign-on command: status -1
avrdude: jtagmkII_getsync(): sign-on command: status -1
avrdude: jtagmkII_getsync(): sign-on command: status -1
avrdude: jtagmkII_getsync(): sign-on command: status -1
avrdude: jtagmkII_getsync(): sign-on command: status -1
avrdude: jtagmkII_getsync(): sign-on command: status -1
avrdude: jtagmkII_getsync(): sign-on command: status -1
avrdude: jtagmkII_getsync(): sign-on command: status -1
avrdude: jtagmkII_getsync(): sign-on command: status -1
avrdude: jtagmkII_getsync(): sign-on command: status -1
avrdude: jtagmkII_getsync(): sign-on command: status -1
avrdude: jtagmkII_getsync(): sign-on command: status -1
avrdude: jtagmkII_getsync(): sign-on command: status -1
avrdude: jtagmkII_getsync(): sign-on command: status -1
avrdude: jtagmkII_getsync(): sign-on command: status -1
avrdude: jtagmkII_getsync(): sign-on command: status -1
avrdude: jtagmkII_getsync(): sign-on command: status -1
avrdude: jtagmkII_getsync(): sign-on command: status -1
avrdude: jtagmkII_getsync(): sign-on command: status -1
An error occurred while uploading the sketch
```

Here are the settings I'm currently using:

- Board is set to Arduino Nano Every, using Arduino MegaAVR Boards
  1.8.6
- Registers emulation:  none (ATMEGA4809)
- Port:  COM1 (there are no other options that appear for me, and no
  other port pops up in the device manager when I plug the board in)
- Programmer:  Onboard Atmel    mEDBG (UNO WiFi Rev2)

Here's what I've tried so far:

- Disabled antivirus
- Uninstalled and reinstalled Arduino IDE
- Turning on registers emulation
- Restarting computer
- Resetting board
- Using different USB cables
- Using different USB ports (3.0 and 2.0)
- Manually installing Arduino drivers to Windows (Windows said the most
  up-to-date drivers were already installed after I specified the
  directory to search in)
- Nothing is connected to the board.
- The pin-13 LED blinks, so there's a bootloader on the board.
- I've reset the board before uploading.

Any help would be very much appreciated.  I'm about to give up and just return the board and swap it for a different one.

Comment: see in Device Manager the USB devices and the COM ports if the descriptions match. did you try a different USB cable?

Comment: @Juraj I'm not sure what you mean by whether the USB devices and COM ports match; their names, descriptions under "details" tab, and location are all different.  I've tried two different cables, yes.

Comment: so if you disconnect the Every, the COM1 disappears and if you connect the Every the COM1 is back?

Comment: No, COM1 is listed in the device manager regardless of whether the Every is plugged in or not.

Comment: A new usb port should pop up when you plug in the Arduino board.  If it doesn't then there is a hardware issue (port or cable or device).  Also, i don't think that jtag is the proper programmer selection.  AVRISP mkII is default programmer I believe.

Comment: that programmer selection is ignored for Serial upload. the upload output in Question is right for Every. COM1 is no the Every. look in Device Manager for unknown USB devices

Comment: I've just tried with another different cable on another different port on my PC.  The same issue persists, so I suspect that the fault is not with the cable or USB port.  There is no unknown USB device listed under device manager.

Comment: try to reistall the megaavr boards package

Comment: I've already done that.  When I uninstalled the arduino IDE I uninstalled all associated files, including board packages.

Comment: uninstalling the IDE doesn't uninstall the boards packages

Comment: I'm aware of that.  I manually deleted all Arduino files everywhere I found them on my computer; original installation, documents library, and appdata.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a trick I use on some boards but first be the baud rate is the same in the terminal as in the sketch (Serial.begin(115200). If so then remove everything then put a jumper between ground and reset. Then put a jumper between TX and RX (pin o and pin 1 on uno). launch the IDE and what you type in the console should be echoed back to you. If this works the hardware is connected fine.

Answer (score -1):

I was getting the same error when I got my brand new Nano Every.

I had Registers emulation: ATMEGA328

I changed it to None (ATMEGA4809) and it uploaded without problems.

I'm on ubuntu 18.04, and this is after the IDE prompted me to install the megaAVR boards library (1.8.7) of course.

Comment: the emulation selection has nothing to do with the upload. it was something else.

Comment: Perhaps. Nevertheless I was having trouble uploading my sketch to my arduino nano every. I googled the error and landed on this question. After reading the question and answers, I realized emulation could be my problem, which it was. This answer was an attempt to aid others with my same problem.